# C# dynamically load generic class with dynamic type parameters per strings and strongly typed result

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, activator

I am attempting to take a JSON file that contains data about a generic class (assembly, class name, type parameter names), and dynamically load and instantiate the specified class. I can do this if I use interfaces for the type parameter. However, implementation specifics won't allow me to go this route, so I need to use the specific type parameter classes.

I have the following code so far:

```
var ci = Invoke.GetClassRef(@"D:\ROCT\Debug\x64 Core\Common Complex Functions.dll", "Namespace.Class");
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(DoubleABCAry), typeof(FloatABCAry), typeof(Search3Range), typeof(object) };
var _model = ci.GetType().MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var model = Activator.CreateInstance(_model) as ComplexBaseModel<IModelInput, IModelIOBase, ISearchDimension, object>;
model.Validate();
```

Line 1: loads the assembly and class. No problem there.

Line 2: lists the types that I need to specify name-wise via a `string[]`.

Line 4: `DoubleABCAry` implements `IModelInput`; `FloatABCAry` implements `IModelIOBase`, etc.

Line 4 is casting the object to its base definition (shown), which is not what I want. I want `RGB255ToCIELAB : ComplexBaseModel<DoubleABCAry, FloatABCAry, Search3Range, object>`.

Line 5 shows that the class is correctly understood. However, the class clearly is implementing interfaces, not the specific types I need.

Is there a way to achieve these two objectives:

1. Use string names to specify each type parameter.
2. Ultimately have `model` strongly typed as explained?

I know it's achievable with dynamically compiled code, but that is my last resort.

I am using C# 9 preview.

Comment: Why can't you cast to `ComplexBaseModel<DoubleABCAry, FloatABCAry, Search3Range, object>`?

Comment: If I could cast it, I wouldn't need to go to this trouble. I would need to hard code the cast, which means I wouldn't need to dynamically load it based on a string.

Comment: So then just invoke your method dynamically, too, and do not cast it with safecast operator you used?

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% follow. Only the correct class contains the needed methods, which cannot be implemented via interface since the method signatures vary. So, I have to have the correct type. I continued to Google this and have seen it isn't possible to do what I want as C# has no way to declare the object as of a specific type (without casting, which, as mentioned, means I wouldn't need dynamic code). Unless you know how to do this and can show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think ultimately your problem boils down to the fact that you want to load `dynamic` types but then treat them as `static` such that you can invoke methods using `instance.MyMethod()` syntax. This is **not** possible (AFAIC) simply because `instance.MyMethod()` is compiled down to IL and at that point compiler does not know what `instance` is.

So provided you do not have any way of knowing what is the method you want to invoke, you have to go full dynamic route, i.e. use reflection APIs to invoke the right method.

So you would need to supply not just class name but also method name or have a convention e.g. `always invoke method called 'Validate'` or something similar.

A simple listing below illustrates my point:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Shoes {
    
    public interface IA { }
    public class A : IA {}

    public interface IB { }
    public class B : IB {}

    public class SomeKindOfModel<T1, T2> { 

    }

    public class ConcreteModel<T1, T2> : SomeKindOfModel<T1, T2> {
       public bool Validate() {
           return true;
       }    
    }

    public class Program
    {   
        public static void Main()
        {
            // since i don't have your Invoke.GetClassRef, i just did this, works in .net core
            var type = Type.GetType($"Shoes.ConcreteModel`2");

            var genType = type.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(A), typeof(B) });
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genType);
            var result = genType.GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Invoke(instance, null); // instead of null you can pass data etc.
            Console.WriteLine(result); // prints True
        }
    }
}
```